# Is there a faster way to loop over an array in safe mode

Tags: c#, arrays, pointers, unsafe

I am writing a method to measure the frequency of a sampled sine wave. It takes a somewhat large 1D array (10^3 to 10^4 samples order of magnitude) and returns a `double`. A helper methods is also called within the body of the method that checks whether the wave is crossing zero. Here is an example of what I have written:

```
public static double Hertz(float[] v, int n) {
    int nZCros = 0
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if (IsZeroCrossing(v.Skip(i - 1).ToArray())) {
            ++nZCros;
        }
    }
    return (double)nZCros / 2.0;
}
private static bool IsZeroCrossing(float[] v) {
    bool cross;
    //checks if the first two elements of the array are opposite sign or not
    return cross;
}
```

My problem is that method takes 200-300 ms to run. So I decided to try using `unsafe` and pointers, like this,

```
public unsafe static double Hertz(float* v, int n) {
    int nZCros = 0
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if (IsZeroCrossing(&v[i - 1])) {
            ++nZCros;
        }
    }
    return (double)nZCros / 2.0;
}
private unsafe static bool IsZeroCrossing(float* v) {
    bool cross;
    //checks if the first two elements of the array are opposite sign or not
    return cross;
}
```

which runs in 2-4 ms.

However, I am not really comfortable with venturing outside the recommended bounds. Is there a way to achieve the same speed in a safe context? And if there isn't, does it defeat the purpose of using C#? Should I really be using C# for these kind of signal processing applications and scientific implementations?

This is just one of many DSP methods I'm writing which take a large array of samples as an input. But this one got me to realize there was a problem, because I accidentally put in 48000 samples instead of 4800 when I was testing this method and it took 20 seconds to return a value.

Thank you.

**UPDATE:** I tried adding `Take(2)` after `Skip(i - 1)` in the former snippet. This brought it down to 90-100 ms, but the question still stands.

Comment: I strongly suspect it's not the safe-vs-unsafe decision that's making the difference here; it's the `v.Skip(i - 1).ToArray()`.

Comment: I did suspect that. So LINQ is the culprit?

Comment: I would say misuse of LINQ is the culprit.  Definitely, converting an enumerable to an array on every iteration is going to be way more expensive than just passing an array with an offset.

Comment: But without LINQ, is there a way pass arrays with a different starting index than 0?

Comment: Yes.  Pass both the array and the starting index.

Comment: That's what the offset is for.

Comment: That seems sound @adv12. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to pass a copy of the array elements to `IsZeroCrossing()`.

Instead, just pass the two elements you are interested in:

```
private static bool IsZeroCrossing(float elem1, float elem2)
{
    return elem1*elem2 < 0.0f; // Quick way to check if signs differ.
}
```

And call it like so:

```
if (IsZeroCrossing(v[i-1], v[i]) {
```

It's possible that such a simple method will be inlined for a release build, making it as fast as possible.

Comment: +1 This is a good answer, but it doesn't reach the heart of the bigger problem I was alluding too. I have other methods which do take the rest of the array from the offset and not just the first two elements.

Comment: @skwear, then in those cases, pass the array and the offset as suggested in the comments.

Comment: Thanks @adv12. I have quite a bit of refactoring to do.